# Add multiple ids in getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

How to use this script with multiple ids? Does not work on the second id that I try to add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = (function () {
var elem = document.getElementById("id1","id2").onclick = function()
{
fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to select many items by their IDs:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#id2, #id3, #id5');

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
  items[i].onclick = function() { 
    this.innerText = this.innerText + '!';
  };
}
```

```html
2, 3, 5 are working:

<p id="id1">I am 1</p><p id="id2">I am 2</p><p id="id3">I am 3</p><p id="id4">I am 4</p><p id="id5">I am 5</p>
```

However, creating a common class sounds much better.

Comment: this solved my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

getElementById only takes one ID, but you can do this to select more than one element:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#id1, #id2');
```

...but you should not use that to create an event listener for every element. Better create one event listener for the whole document instead, for example:

```
document.addEventListener('click', handleClickEvents, false);

function handleClickEvents(evt) {
    myEventTarget = event.target;

    if (myEventTarget.id === 'id1') {

    } else if (myEventTarget.id === 'id2) {

    }
}
```

...or even better, use a framework like React or Angular.

Comment: please comment a reason if you downvote something, i am happy to improve my answer.

Comment: The very first line of your code is wrong.

Comment: my bad, fixed it. of course you need hashtags for ids.

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementById` takes only one parameter, the id of the element you want to select. You can't pass to id more than one ids.

For more documentantion on this, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

If you want to select multiple elements and attach to them the same event handler, you can use another approach.

First you have to add the same class to each of them, for instance js-classname.

Then you can select them using the method `getElementsByClassName`. This method will return to you an array like object containing all the elements with the class you specified.

If you need more information about this, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).